# How we can do access confirmation link in email message using Gmail api & Cypress

Tags: gmail-api, cypress

I am stuck with Gmail confirmation while user registration, with cypress, but when I follow this in I saw that one answer:

> I don't think clicking inside the gmail account is necessary. Every link sent when registering apparently has a token. What I would do is try to get from your API/backend that token for that email and add it to the link and visit it using cypress.

How can I do this? I am very new to programming and Cypress.

Comment: Have you been able to find something by Googling the question?

Comment: @Nelles, I tried lot , but I was unable